# Faradays law and EMI confusion

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

According to EMI definition, it is the changing magnetic field acting ON the conductor that induces an emf. However when using Faraday’s law, instead of finding the changing magnetic field acting on the conductor we find the changing magnetic field in the space enclosed by the conductor. Why?

Comment: there can be no (why?) here, because that itself is the law, also EMI definition is based on faraday's law and it seems like you misinterpreted the "ON" part of the definition.

Comment: would an emf still be induced in a straight conductor where area enclosed is zero all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, a changing magnetic field acting on the conductor does not induce an emf. Emf is a an *integral* concept (it is defined as the work per unit charge along a finite path).

What can be said is that a changing magnetic field at one point (independently if there is or  not a conductor) induces a non zero curl of the electric field at the same point. The existence of a local relation involving derivatives, as well as a reasonable assumption of smoothness of the fields, ensures the possibility of recasting the same information in the form of a global (integral) relation between the change of the magnetic flux due to the time variation of  the ${\bf B}$ field, and  emf. At this level, it is possible to combine this result with the expression for motional emf to obtain the Faraday law.

Comment: what? could u use simple language?

Comment: @mad112 I could use a simpler language if I knew what is your background/level.

Comment: explain like i a m five. remember a great mind once said those who can explain simply understand best.

Comment: @mad112  if you were five it would be better to play with magnets, not with theory. Electromagnetism was not invented by children and is not for children. This is a fact. I agree with Einstein's sentence "Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler.". So, I really need to know what is your background, in order to understand what is the possible level of simplification. I suspect you are not comfortable with vector calculus. I am wrong? do you know what the curl of a vector field is?

Comment: no i am not familiar with field curls

Answer (score 0):

found the SIMPLE answer I was looking for while thinking about it myself. gosh it was hidden in plain sight lol. textbooks really dont want our lives to be easy as they never reveal how or why just what (regarding faradays law).